# Functions orthogonal after shifting

Tags: real-analysis

This is easy but I confused myself a lot. Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $u,w,z$ continuous functions such that $(u-z)(w-z)=0$. If $X$ is connected, for fixed $u,w$ are there other functions than $z=\min(u,w)$ and $z=\max(u,w)$ for which this identity holds?

Comment: Your assumption is equivalent to the closed sets $\{u=z\}$ and $\{w=z\}$ covering your space $X$, with intersection $\{u=w\}$. As such, there are many more examples, e.g. $z=u$.